# QT .pro file: show files from sub directory project in Qt Creator tree without compiling them

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Imagine you have a directory sturcture of:

```
top_level_project/
├── top_level_project.pro
├── files/
    ├── ...
├── sub_project/
    ├── sub_project.pro
    ├── files/
        ├── ...
```

and a `top_level_project.pro` of:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = \
    sub_project
```

How would I make it so the sub_project's files are visible in the QtCreator file tree and searchable within the top_level_project project, but the sub_project project doesn't actually get compiled?

---

I tried altering the `sub_project.pro` to only have the `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` lists but it still tries to compile the files in the sub_project project

Answer (score 0):

Turns our all I had to do was a make a `sub_project.pri` file that looks like this:

```
HEADERS += <paths to header files>

SOURCES += <paths to source files>
```

(I used an environment variable to know the paths.)

Then, all I had to do was include that `sub_project.pri` file in the `top_level_project.pro` file as such:

```
include(<path to sub_project.pri>)
```

All files are now visible in the tree and the sub project doesn't get compiled.